# What can you do against fortify-source (stack overflow)?

Tags: stack-overflow

I was practicing stack buffer exploitation on a well known application

I was able to bypass canaries, ASLR and nx bit with techniques easily found on the internet

However it has fortify-source enabled which checks that strcpy does not copy more than the buffer size, (the size of the buffer is compile-time known)

Is it impossible to exploit in this case?